# Pax exam karaf 4.0.7 using mock javamail

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, karaf, pax-exam

I would like use javamail-mock2 in pax exam environment but the problem is that pax exam cannot see META-INF folder from test. How to add javamail.providers file to suite that javamail-mock2 will see configuration file and load mock providers?

MP

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
```

test/java/resources/META-INF/javamail.providers

```
protocol=mock_smtp; type=transport; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.MockTransport; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=mock_smtps; type=transport; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.MockTransport; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=mock_pop3; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.POP3MockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=mock_imap; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.IMAPMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=mock_pop3s; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.POP3SSLMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=mock_imaps; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.IMAPSSLMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
#Override real providers
protocol=smtp${mock.postfix}; type=transport; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.MockTransport; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=smtps${mock.postfix}; type=transport; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.MockTransport; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=pop3${mock.postfix}; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.POP3MockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=imap${mock.postfix}; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.IMAPMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=pop3s${mock.postfix}; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.POP3SSLMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
protocol=imaps${mock.postfix}; type=store; class=de.saly.javamail.mock2.IMAPSSLMockStore; vendor=JavaMail Mock2 provider;
```

And finally I get error:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for mock_imaps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javamail-mock2 is maybe not compatible with OSGi. We have a mock-mail bundle we build and use for testing Camel in OSGi at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/tests/test-bundles/mock-javamail_1.7

Comment: We came with solution to use GreenMail but use osgi bundle as you provide it will better solution, thx.